# calculate the difference betwen Two values on the same document

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongo aggregation.I want to calculate the difference betwen Two values  (The last collection for each day -The first collection for each day).the data base record data every 5 mn for many ressource name.The structucture of the document is :

```
{    
    _id : ObjectId("5820511a95d447ed648b45d6"),
    DeviceName : "OLT01FTV",
    ResourceName : "CM MAC:00-07-11-11-39-20",
    CollectionTime : ISODate("2016-11-07T09:30:00.000+01:00"),
    GranularityPeriod : 5,
    A : 0,
    B: 17,
    C: 4,
    D: 21,
    E: 3,
    F: 0
}
```

A,B...F are the differrent counters.
Below, the illustration of that I'm trying to have :

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygxg0.png)

```
([
    { "$match": { 
        "CollectionTime": { 
            $gte: ISODate("2016-09-05T00:00:00.000Z"), 
            $lt: ISODate("2016-10-07T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$u2000" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "firstUC": { "$first": "$UC" },
        "lastUC": { "$last": "$UC" },
        "firstSM-MISS": { "$first": "$SM-MISS" },
        "lastSM-MISS": { "$last": "$SM-MISS" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "diff": {
            "$divide": [
                { "$subtract": [ "$firstUC", "$lastUC" ] },
                { "$subtract": [ "$firstSM-MISS", "$lastSM-MISS" ] }
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the difference between the 'A' values for your above scenario.  You can add the other fields if you want to get the difference for them also.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "CollectionTime": {
            $gte: ISODate("2016-11-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
            $lt: ISODate("2016-11-30T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "CollectionTime": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "firstA": { "$first": "$A" },
        "lastA": { "$last": "$A" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        _id: 0,
        diffA: {
            $subtract: [ "$lastA", "$firstA"]
        }
    }}
])
```

*** EDIT ***

So I'm using the following sample documents I created with the following to match your schema:

```
// Create 3 Documents 1 second apart
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    db.foo.insert({    
        DeviceName : "OLT01FTV",
        ResourceName : "CM MAC:00-07-11-11-39-20",
        CollectionTime : new Date(),
        GranularityPeriod : 5,
        A : 1*i,
        B: 2*i,
        C: 3*i,
        D: 4*i,
        E: 5*i,
        F: 6*i
    })

    sleep(1000); // To add a delay between insertions so we can visibly see the date difference
}
```

This results in the following 3 documents being created:

```
> db.foo.find().pretty()

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582b1a6ced19a7334a5dee31"),
    "DeviceName" : "OLT01FTV",
    "ResourceName" : "CM MAC:00-07-11-11-39-20",
    "CollectionTime" : ISODate("2016-11-15T14:23:40.934Z"),
    "GranularityPeriod" : 5,
    "A" : 1,
    "B" : 2,
    "C" : 3,
    "D" : 4,
    "E" : 5,
    "F" : 6
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582b1a6ded19a7334a5dee32"),
    "DeviceName" : "OLT01FTV",
    "ResourceName" : "CM MAC:00-07-11-11-39-20",
    "CollectionTime" : ISODate("2016-11-15T14:23:41.936Z"),
    "GranularityPeriod" : 5,
    "A" : 2,
    "B" : 4,
    "C" : 6,
    "D" : 8,
    "E" : 10,
    "F" : 12
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582b1a6eed19a7334a5dee33"),
    "DeviceName" : "OLT01FTV",
    "ResourceName" : "CM MAC:00-07-11-11-39-20",
    "CollectionTime" : ISODate("2016-11-15T14:23:42.939Z"),
    "GranularityPeriod" : 5,
    "A" : 3,
    "B" : 6,
    "C" : 9,
    "D" : 12,
    "E" : 15,
    "F" : 18
}
```

The first step of the aggregation pipeline will match on all documents between the date range - which I set to beginning of November... so no worry there, then the sorting will sort by collection time:

After the grouping we have one document with the firstA and lastA value:

```
{ "_id" : null, "firstA" : 1, "lastA" : 3 }
```

And finally - perform the subtract in the projection and hide the ID field:

```
{ "diffA" : 2 }
```

Comment: It's not working, i get the following result :{
 "_id" : null,
 "diffA" : null
}

Comment: Please see edit.  It's working just fine.  I think you need to change the dates to match your needs.